# Pie chart with slice filled in different percentage

Tags: charts, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I am wondering if any possible way is there to make slices in pie chart show how much percentage of complete.
I need to make a pie chart like below [image: pie-chart with slice percentage]

I tried to research and having a close match to my expectation with the polar chart except I need the slice's size are different like a normal pie chart:

```
 `Jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/lishace/ymjzow06/1/
```

Does polar chart have config to change the size of slice or can we show the percentage for each slice in pie chart?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this chart using `pie` and `variablepie` series on top of each other. Variable pie point takes `z` value which in your case will be the percentage of completed.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oxfjkhL8/